# RetainCount is -1 after alloc?

Tags: nsstring, retaincount

Please don't mark Duplicate:-
I have created the few lines

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init];
str = @"Test";
NSLog(@"%d",[str retainCount]);
```

and Output is -1 .Please explain.

Comment: It is a duplicate, though.   See www.whentouseretaincount.com.

Comment: You even KNEW it was a dupe

Comment: RetainCount is -1 because you ask for a constant string that is never released anyways

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a dupe of the question I pointed to.   It is -1 because you are printing UINT_MAX as a signed integer.  The RC is -1 because that is a singleton string generated by the compiler, effectively, and is never allocated or deallocated.

This pattern:

```
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init];
    str = @"Kashyap";
```

Makes no sense;  you are allocating a string instance, assigning a reference to it to `str` in the first line, and then immediately overwriting that reference in the second line (and leaking the first string, if you aren't using ARC).

If there is a tutorial or book that is advocating that anti-pattern, please point it out.