# iOS - Reference Count Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk

I am doing some work on reference count increase. Below is the sample.

.h file.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *s1;
```

.m file

@synthesize s1;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    s1 = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%d",[s1 retainCount]);

    [s1 retain];
    NSLog(@"%d",[s1 retainCount]);

    [s1 copy];
    NSLog(@"%d",[s1 retainCount]);
}
```

When i am finding reference count, it is showing -1 for all of them, and i am bit confused for this, please help me.

Comment: NEVER use `retainCount`- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount/4636477#4636477

Comment: Just to emphasize: Never use retainCount. And do yourself a favour and start using ARC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RetainCount is -1 after alloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728133/retaincount-is-1-after-alloc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It prints -1 because you're using the wrong string format.

Since `retainCount` returns a `NSUIngeter` (i.e. and unsigned integer), you should use

```
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)myNSUInteger);
```

Other than that, it's worth remarking that you should **never** rely on `retainCount`.

See [When To You Retain Count](http://www.whentouseretaincount.com/).

Also, from the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount):

> This method is of no value in debugging memory management issues.
>   Because any number of framework objects may have retained an object in
>   order to hold references to it, while at the same time autorelease
>   pools may be holding any number of deferred releases on an object, **it
>   is very unlikely that you can get useful information from this method**.